# Magento 2 : Change text "Please enter a valid email address (Ex: johndoe@domain.com)." in validation

Tags: magento2, validation

I am using Magento 2.3.4 and 
want to  Change text "`Please enter a valid email address (Ex: johndoe@domain.com).`" in validation.
in email validation , login field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/lib/validation/rules.js` (line 446 and 452)
this message is translated 
, I think you don't have the right translation in your translation file
, You can manually add that into your language file

Comment: How to override it ?

Comment: You don't need to override this, all you need to override is csv file who contains this translation you can add just csv file in you theme like this app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/i18n/en_US.csv or add csv file in your custom module file like in this tutorial https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-add-translation-csv-in-magento2/ ; in your csv you just add something like : "Please enter a valid email address (Ex: johndoe@domain.com).", "here your text translated"

Comment: the problem is not this file but the csv file who contains your translation, this text is not translated in your csv file

Comment: if i add this translation for en_US.csv then it will work for this language only right ?

Comment: yes you add this in en_US.csv then it work for store en , if you put it in fr_FR.csv then it work for store fr, etc ....

Comment: Ok so its about Store. & if i change currency to something different then will it work ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106823/discussion-between-developer-and-freddy-hattedd).

Comment: translate depend on store not currency, you can read the document from here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html

Comment: Great answer , can i use this file in my module ?

Comment: Yes like in this tutorial https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-add-translation-csv-in-magento2/  , you create folder named 'i18n'  inside your custom module and you create en_US.csv for example inside this folder

Comment: Can you please share your thoughts on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/310551/how-to-add-not-empty-validation-to-login-email-address-field-on-checkout-page ?

Comment: I'm just a magento lovers not pro magento :)  , i suggest you to read this tutorial https://aureatelabs.com/magento-2/add-custom-validation-rule-in-magento-2/  , i think it can help you for you question here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/310551/how-to-add-not-empty-validation-to-login-email-address-field-on-checkout-page

Comment: what if there are 6 stores , do i need to add 6 csv files for that ?

Comment: Yes 6 csv file according to the name of your store

Comment: Thanks & what if the store view has code "(Code: ca)" , then how to determine the name of the csv file ?